# Has edit functionality changed? I cannot edit just tags

Tags: bug, tags, suggested-edits, too-minor

Ran into an issue on gamedev.se that wouldn't allow me to edit just the tags for a question.

[Did Edit functionality change?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/did-edit-functionality-change)

It was suggested that maybe this was a recent change for all of SE. I was able to edit tags, via the normal "edit" button on a question as of Oct 8. Now it appears to be looking for a significant change to the question's content as well to allow me to submit an edit.

Is this a new feature or issue within SE?

### Update:

I am able to put just tag edits into the review queue now, via the "edit" button. My best assumption is that I may have accidentally edited the question text in some insignificant way. However, it occurred even when reloading the question.

If this occurs again I'll update this question with some more diagnostic info from the inspector.

### Update (2016-10-21):

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/103962/edit

I'm having the same problem with editing this question. The only thing I can think of is that it has an answer. Most of the tag edits I've been doing have been questions with no answers (I'm looking for unanswered questions for a specific tag, and finding a lot of mistagged questions).

**Form Data:**

```
is-current:true
warntags:
title:Create ROI tools for analysis
post-text:I want to create some ROI tools on my game for personal analysis.

Let's say that I have 3 different level of special powers with a recursive cost and certain bonus. So, I want to see when certain level will start have income.

1st example: 1000 coins for 10 uses. Bonus: +10% on farming speed. 2000 coins for 10 uses. Bonus: +20% on farming speed. Etc

In this example, I know exactly what the bonus will do. I have the price of the farming per unit and I can calculate the income per use for each power level. So, I can tweak the numbers using the ROI tool to make the effect better.

2nd example: 1000 coins for 3 power ups on a weapon. Bonus: +1 attack power, +5% chance to destroy the weapon. 2000 coins for 3 power ups on a weapon. Bonus: +2 attacking power, 10% chance to destroy the weapon.

3rd example: 1000 coins per use. Bonus: 30% heal, 5% chance to get injured. 2000 coins per use. Bonus: 50% heal, 10% chance to get injured.

As you can see, the first example is simple to calculate the income vs cost. However, the second and third example don't have an exact effect and both of them have a probability to either good or bad effect. How do you work on this type of ROI? How do you calculate the pros of each level? 
fkey:(redacted)
author:
tagnames:game-design tools analytics balance 
edit-comment:Adding Balance
```

**Form Data URL Encoded:**

```
is-current:true
warntags:
title:Create+ROI+tools+for+analysis
post-text:I+want+to+create+some+ROI+tools+on+my+game+for+personal+analysis.%0D%0A%0D%0ALet's+say+that+I+have+3+different+level+of+special+powers+with+a+recursive+cost+and+certain+bonus.+So%2C+I+want+to+see+when+certain+level+will+start+have+income.%0D%0A%0D%0A1st+example%3A+1000+coins+for+10+uses.+Bonus%3A+%2B10%25+on+farming+speed.+2000+coins+for+10+uses.+Bonus%3A+%2B20%25+on+farming+speed.+Etc%0D%0A%0D%0AIn+this+example%2C+I+know+exactly+what+the+bonus+will+do.+I+have+the+price+of+the+farming+per+unit+and+I+can+calculate+the+income+per+use+for+each+power+level.+So%2C+I+can+tweak+the+numbers+using+the+ROI+tool+to+make+the+effect+better.%0D%0A%0D%0A2nd+example%3A+1000+coins+for+3+power+ups+on+a+weapon.+Bonus%3A+%2B1+attack+power%2C+%2B5%25+chance+to+destroy+the+weapon.+2000+coins+for+3+power+ups+on+a+weapon.+Bonus%3A+%2B2+attacking+power%2C+10%25+chance+to+destroy+the+weapon.%0D%0A%0D%0A3rd+example%3A+1000+coins+per+use.+Bonus%3A+30%25+heal%2C+5%25+chance+to+get+injured.+2000+coins+per+use.+Bonus%3A+50%25+heal%2C+10%25+chance+to+get+injured.%0D%0A%0D%0AAs+you+can+see%2C+the+first+example+is+simple+to+calculate+the+income+vs+cost.+However%2C+the+second+and+third+example+don't+have+an+exact+effect+and+both+of+them+have+a+probability+to+either+good+or+bad+effect.+How+do+you+work+on+this+type+of+ROI%3F+How+do+you+calculate+the+pros+of+each+level%3F+
fkey:(redacted)
author:
tagnames:game-design+tools+analytics+balance+
edit-comment:Adding+Balance
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: 64c9fa3c-1619-463d-bbb1-d03d1b7b7566
Content-Length: 151
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2016 03:47:44 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-jfk8151-JFK
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1477108064.260702,VS0,VE62
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off

{
    "success": false,
    "errors": {
        "Body": ["Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"]
    },
    "warnings": {},
    "source": {}
}
```

## Additional Affected Questions

- [Finite State Machine Input Handling](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131487/finite-state-machine-input-handling)

Comment: as per my answer on the original meta question, I am commenting to confirm that I was able to perform a tag-only edit, [removing the tag unityscript from a question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/revisions/131300/2).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm gonna close this question for now; ping me if you get more information later.

Comment: @AdamLear I've encountered the issue again, added request and response data.

Comment: You should not make the `fkey` form value public, that's the anti-forgery token. Since it's public now, I'd advise you log out and back in to invalidate your session.

Comment: Reproduced, getting same error as well when trying to add the balance tag.

Comment: @balpha thanks, I avoided posting the request headers, but didn't know there was security in the form data itself. Logged out/in just now.